# The continuous image of a sequentially compact set is also sequentially compact.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

Let $S$ be a sequentially compact set and let $f : S\to R$ be continuous. Then the image $f(S)$ is sequentially compact.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By definition of sequential compactness, we must show that every $(y_n) \subseteq f(S)$ has a convergent subsequence. To this end, pick $(y_n)$ in $f(S)$ arbitrary. Since $y_n \in f(S) $, then $y_n = f(x_n) $ for some $x_n \in S$. By sequential compactness of $S$, $(x_n)$ contains a subsequence $x_{n_k} $ that converges in $S$, say $x_{n_k} \to l \in S$. Since $f$ is continuous, then $f(x_{n_k}) \to f(l) \in f(S) $. Notice $f(x_{n_k})$ is a subsequence of $(y_n)$. Since $(y_n)$ was chosen arbitrarily, then $f(S)$ must be sequentially compact.

Answer (score 0):

Take a sequence in $f(S)$. By definition, it is an image of some sequence in $S$. Use the sequential compactness of $S$ to get what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence in $S$. It has a convergent subsequence $(a_{n_k})$. Since $f$ is continuous, $(f(a_{n_k}))$ converges as well.